# утечка памяти при удалении элемента DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, dom, память

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение, которое должно работать длительное время, все это время в нем удаляются/создаются элементы таблицы(элементы загружаются с сервера). Удаляю строки при помощи jquery(.remove()).Однако элементы при удалении не удаляются из памяти, отладчик показывает, что при каждом создании нового элемента растет "private memory", но после удаления не очищается. Пробовал предварительно, перед удалением, отвязывать обработчики при помощи метода .off, обнулять ссылку на удаленный элемент, но ничего из этого особенно не помогает и память продолжает утекать! Может кто нибудь знает как удалить элемент DOM из памяти совсем? Или, возможно, есть другие выходы из ситуации?

Comment: Без конкретного кода сказать трудно

Comment: В полном снаряжении функция выглядит так:
`$("#mainTable").children().each(function(){
        $(this).off();
        let delX = $(this).remove();
        delX = null;
    });`

Comment: В таком коде очень вряд ли могут быть утечки, могу лишь предположить, что элементы ещё используются каким-то другим кодом